# How to exclude a specific categogy from a custom page template

Tags: categories, loop

I have a custom page template that uses the wordpress loop to display all my posts like usual:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

There is a category that I don't want to display on this page. The id of this category is 3.

So I though I could use something like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
          if ( in_category('3') ) continue;
               the_content();
          endwhile;
      endif; 
?>
```

But the posts with this category ID are still displaying.

I've also tried adding this to functions.php:

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if (isset($query)) {
        $query->set('cat', '-3');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

This works, but it is global to every page on the site (obviously), which is what I don't want. I just want category ID removed from this single page template.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What do you mean custom page template? `pre_get_posts` doesn't work on page templates. Exactly what template?

Comment: its a custom template called location-template.php. I used "pre_get_posts" in the functions.php file. This works to exclude the category from anywhere the wordpress loop is being used. I just want to exclude this category from being displayed in location-template.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( is_page('slug-of-page') && isset($query) ) {
        $query->set('cat', '-3');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and the posts in that category are still showing up on the page with the slug that I give it. also tried is_page_template('location-template.php'), but I'm not sure these will work in functions.php because functions.php is loaded before the page loads.

Comment: Try it without the quotes: `if ( in_category(3) ) continue;`  Maybe WP is parsing 3 as a string, not an integer, so it's looking for a Category called "3", not an Category with an ID of 3.

Comment: Yeah that still didn't work :(

Comment: This is technically the blog template. The posts in that category are displaying on /blog/page/9/. --- I wonder if /blog/page/9/ is a different template?

Comment: Take that back, removing the quotes seemed to fix it! thanks buddy! :)

Comment: So does the answer reflect the code you used or should it be edited?